# Slight difference in Future.zip and Future.zipWith implementation. Why?

Tags: scala

Let's consider the following excerpt from `scala.concurrent.Future.scala`:

```
def zip[U](that: Future[U]): Future[(T, U)] = {
    implicit val ec = internalExecutor
    flatMap { r1 => that.map(r2 => (r1, r2)) }
  }

def zipWith[U, R](that: Future[U])(f: (T, U) => R)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[R] =
    flatMap(r1 => that.map(r2 => f(r1, r2)))(internalExecutor)
```

It does not differ a lot seemingly, except for the application of function `f` in the `zipWith` case. It is interesting to me, why the `internalExecutor` (which just delegates to the current thread) is declared as implicit value in the `zip` and thus used in both underlying `map` and `flatMap` calls, but is used explicitly only in the `flatMap` call inside the `zipWith`?

As I understand after some thinking, the `f` function execution may involve some blocking or intensive computation which is out of Scala library control, and so the user should provide another execution context for it to not occasionally block the `internalExecutor` (current thread). Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Well... both implementations will ignore any other `implicitly` available `ExecutionContext` and will use the `ExecutionContext` which is used for `this` `Future`.

Comment: This `internalExecutor` is a special executor which is supposed to used for all callbacks which should be hidden from the developer who may not want these internal callbacks to pollute his application critical execution context. Which is to say, that the execution of of both `this` and `that` `Future` will happen in application's `ExecutionContext` (whichever available in scope) but all the callback which will create this result future will execute in `internalExecutor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application of `f` is done with the supplied `ExecutionContext`, and `internalExecutor` is used to perform the flattening operation. The rule is basically: When the user supplies the logic, that logic is executed on the `ExecutionContext` supplied by the user.

You could imagine that `zipWith` was implemented as `this.zip(that).map(f.tupled)` or that `zip` was implemented as `zipWith(Tuple2.apply)(internalExecutor)`.

Comment: I've also found your 'several posts describing the evolution of scala.concurrent.Future in Scala 2.12.x" which covers these two methods and some other stuff as well. Thanks.